# Nginx redirection on paginations

Tags: redirect, nginx

I am trying to using Nginx to redirect from `/t/latest/2` to `/topics/latest/page/2`

```
rewrite ^/t/latest$      /topics/latest permanent;
rewrite ^/t/latest/(.*)$      /topics/latest/page/$1 permanent;
```

This works well, but I am wondering if there is a smarter way to do this in one rule? This is because there are many redirects like this and it would be nice if I can cut the redundancy.

Comment: what are some examples of the similar URLs that want to do this for? Maybe there is a regex or two which can handle all the cases.

Comment: oh an answer to combine the two mentioned above would be fine, since other pages can be quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no way to accomplish this in a single rule. If such a thing is possible, I expect to look more contorted than the two simple lines you have here.

However, another approach I use may benefit your project. My nginx configurations are generated from templates. Each time the server is started or restarts, the "init" script runs a Perl scripts which fills in the template from a configuration file. Nginx then "includes" this file. This is being used in production and works well.

This solutions provides you another option for cutting down the time required to configure nginx, while still leaving you with readable `rewrite` directives.